# How to reload js script after ajax call?

Tags: jquery

I have this script called `admin_order.js`, which works fine.  Due to a certain plugin which loads ajax content after ajax content has been loaded `admin_order.js` now doesn't work.

I tried this in the response function but no success.

```
$.getScript("../../themes/mywebsite/js/admin_order.js");
```

How do i reload the script?

Comment: So is the `admin_order.js` modified on the server due to the `ajax` ca;;s? If not I would investigate further why your script stops working. If yes, then maybe you should restructure your code.

Comment: No, nothing is modified.  The html that the ajax call returns replaces the html that `admin_order.js` has events attached to but the class names of those elements remain the same.. Any idea?

Comment: So why don't you query for data only with the `ajax` call and update the content on the front end? Your current solution partially reloads the page and I guess reloading the page (`location.reload();`) doesn't work as you end up in the wrong state.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem must be handled in another way; but if you can't handle this in the plugin code, you can:

1. add an id to the script element eg myAdminOrderScript
2. before the `getScript` remove the script element
3. in the `getScript` success function add an Id to the last script element

Like:

```
<script id="myAdminOrderScript" src="../../themes/mywebsite/js/admin_order.js"></script>

  function reloadScript() {
    $('#myAdminOrderScript').remove();
    $.getScript("../../themes/mywebsite/js/admin_order.js", function() {
      $('script:last').attr('id', 'myAdminOrderScript');
    });
  }
```

Comment: thanks, do i put this in the ajax response function?

Comment: Yes, or in the getScript (taht is a shortcut of ajax) as the example